# programar la funcion promedio de Excel en javascript o otro lenguaje

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayuda para saber como  puedo calcular el promedio de  esta tabla, donde la tercera columna es el valor a calcular
en excel. La fórmula sería algo así: `Promedio(0.63,518:461,0.60:0.70);` solo que no se me ocurre como  programarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El promedio, sobre qué tipo de datos lo harías? ¿un array? ¿Tenés una base del código hecha, la cual sirva para contestarte más específicamente sobre tu caso?

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta información clave para poder ayudarte: ¿Podrías explicar cómo se obtiene 499.0 haciendo el promedio de 518 y 461?¿Para que sirven los coeficientes 0.6, 0.7 y 0.63? Copiando la función tal cual la tienes puesta en la pregunta en Excel, recibo un fallo diciendo que hay errores en la formula, ¿la tienes así tal cual en Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es calcular la media de todos los valores de un `Array` es algo bastante sencillo en JavaScript.

El objeto [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) tiene un maravilloso método [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) con el cual puedes conseguir lo que quieres de manera bastante elegante:

```
const sum = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
const avg = sum / values.length
```

Comment: El código que compartes no coincide con lo esperado. Según OP para 518 y 461, el resultado debería ser 499.0 (la tercera columna), pero ejecutándolo se obtiene 489.5

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no pretendía que el código resolviese la pregunta si no orientar sobre cómo calcular la media. En cualquier caso hay algún dato que se escapa.